# prove the set of all functions such that $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ where $|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-y|$ form a group under composition

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let f be a function $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ where $|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-y|$

prove that the set of all such functions forms a group under composition.

I think this is the set of all linear functions, yes? since $f(x)=x+z$, $z\in \mathbb{Z}$, satisfies this property. It just 'shifts' this 'gap' in some direction along the number line. I assume this works:

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|=|a+z-(b+z)|=|a-b+(z-z)|=|a-b|$

I think this has closure since the composition $f(g(x))=f(x+z)=x+2z$ where $2z \in \mathbb{Z}$ since $(Z,+)$ is itself a group.

I am not really sure how to identify and prove the existence of the identity here since this is dealing with a set of functions. Any guidance/hints?

---

And as a note - If you've noticed me posting abstract alg. questions over the past day or two it is because I am doing ever problem/exercise/proof given by our prof. over the course of the last month to prepare myself for an exam! None of these are assigned for grading.

Comment: Functions of the form $f(x)=a-x$ also satisfy the codition.

Comment: There are other functions, like $f(x)=-x$, so that isn't enough.

Comment: It's not because the linear functions satisfies this property that every function that satisfy this property is a linear function

Comment: If your operation is composition of functions, then there is only one possible identity element, and that is the aptly named identity function $f_e(x) = x$.

Comment: So consider $z=0$. Then x can be any value from the integers. Then I have covered $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=-x$ , yes? Since $a,x \in \mathbb{z}$ then I have also covered $f(x)=a-x$. Or so I thought. If not, why not? Should I explicitly state these things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that functions of the form $f(x)=a-x$ also satsify the contition.

But it seems to be a detour to want to describe *exactly* which functions are in the group. It's not *too* hard to show that it is exactly the functions of the form $a-x$ and $a+x$, but it's still a detour, and could be viewed as inelegant to have to split everything into these *two* cases (which multiply into four for composition) instead of working directly from the definition and avoiding the splitting completely.

If you can suppress your desire to know *which* functions you're talking about, it is easy to prove directly from the defining property that it $f$ and $g$ both have it, then $f\circ g$ has the same property -- and that if $f$ has the property then it is bijective, and its inverse must have the same property.

> **Aside** proving that $f$ must be bijective: First, if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|=0$ so $|x-y|=0$ which means that $x=y$. Thus we have shown that $f$ has to be *injective*. Now to show that $f$ is surjective, let $y$ be arbitrary and we must show that $y$ is in the range of $f$. Let $m=|f(0)-y|$. If $m=0$ then $y=f(0)$ and we're done. Otherwise each of $m$ and $-m$ must map to one of $f(0)+m$ and $f(0)-m$; since $f$ is injective they can't both map to the same one, so $f(0)+m$ and $f(0)-m$ are both in the range of $f$; one of them must be $y$ and we're done.

As always when we're talking about composition of functions, the identity element must be the identity function $f(x)=x$. (You'll need to show that it is in the group as defined, of course).

In principle you should also check that the operation is *associative*, but you get that for free when the operation is function composition; that is always associative no matter which functions we're speaking of.

Incidentally the group in question is known as the [infinite dihedral group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_dihedral_group).

Comment: Henning - I am only about 4 weeks into this subject. Perhaps you might show how you would write a piece of this proof (proving the inverse, ident. etc.) and then I can use that to try and complete the proof? I follow your reasoning but sometimes proving things despite them seeming obvious is still a challenge for me.

Comment: @mathtastic: BigM has given some of it. I've amended my answer with a sketch of the difficult part, namely showing that $f$ is necessarily bijective.

Comment: Henning - I completely forgot to mention this earlier - I identified the functions because the practice question asked me to first identify these functions and then prove that the set of functions is a group under composition! I think first identifying them just blinded me. I started working with the functions I found rather than taking a more general approach like the one your outlined here.  Thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Call that set with composition $G$. Note that each element of $G$ must be a bijection in order to have well-defined operation.
Obviously identity function belongs to $G$.if $f,g\in G$ then
$$|f\circ g(x)-f\circ g(y)|=|f(g(x))-f(g(y))|=|g(x)-g(y)|=|x-y|$$ so $f\circ g\in G$.
 $$|x-y|=|f\circ f^{-1}(x)-f\circ f^{-1}(y)|=| f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(y)|$$

Comment: Oh - this is great! Thanks!